# 2 x 2 matrix with positive entries have distinct real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to prove that a real 2 x 2 real matrix with positive entries has two distinct real eigenvalues. If we let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ then the characterstic polynomial is $(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc$ which can be rewritten as $\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc$, I cannot see why the discriminant $(\frac{a+d}{2})^2+bc-ad$ greater than zero, because I have the $-ad$-term.

Comment: You will have to combine the terms...$a^2+2ad+d^2-4ad+4bc=$ what?

Comment: Ah, you get $(a-d)^2+4bc$ which is positive?

Comment: Hint: $(a+d)^2-4ad=(a-d)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The discriminant can be written as $$D=(a-d)^2+4bc$$

Comment: ... which is positive since $b,c$ are positive and $(a-d)^2$ is non-negative since it is square?

Comment: Exactly! Note that $bc>0$ is already sufficient to guarantee two distinct real eigenvalues

Comment: Of course simultaneous change of the signs of $b$ and $c$ is a similarity transformation.